# How to batch zoompan .mp4 using ffmpeg and CMD

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, batch, video-conversion

I need one batch code for ffmpeg which can encode & zoom resolution of all videos inside folder to 110% & 125% of original using batch code.

Here are some codes which I test not working:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a"  -vf scale=2*iw:-1, crop=iw/2:ih/2" "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"

pause
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "zoompan=z='1+(1.4*in/300)':x='70*in/300':y='190*in/300':d=1"  "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "zoompan=z='1+(1.4*in/300"  "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"

error i getting

[code]C:\down\Compressed\DRIVER PACK FOR MOBILE PHONE\DRIVER PACK FOR MOBILE PHONE>ffm
peg -i "avutil-ics-56.dll" -vf "zoompan=z='1+(1.4*in/300"  "newfiles\avutil-ics-
56.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-93461-g6e42021128 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libb
luray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --e
nable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable
-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 -
-enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enab
le-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --en
able-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --en
able-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --e
nable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.105 / 58. 47.105
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
avutil-ics-56.dll: Invalid data found when processing input

C:\down\Compressed\DRIVER PACK FOR MOBILE PHONE\DRIVER PACK FOR MOBILE PHONE>ffm
peg -i "ffmpeg.exe" -vf "zoompan=z='1+(1.4*in/300"  "newfiles\ffmpeg.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-93461-g6e42021128 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libb
luray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --e
nable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable
-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 -
-enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enab
le-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --en
able-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --en
able-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --e
nable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.105 / 58. 47.105
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
ffmpeg.exe: Invalid data found when processing input
[/code]
```

Comment: ffmpeg is trying to process ffmpeg.exe and avutil-ics-56.dll because you are using `for %%a in ("*.*")`.  Change it to `for %%a in ("*.mp4")`

Comment: Your code #2 works on my Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648], my video files, my ffmpeg version 3.4 built with gcc 7.2.0.

Comment: can you kindly post tested code here and how much zoom u put thanks

Comment: `for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "zoompan=z='1+(1.4*in/300)':x='70*in/300':y='190*in/300':d=1" "newfiles\%%~na.mp4" `

Comment: for oeverwrite add ffmpeg -y and mkdir newfiles to make folder then it will work thanks somebadhat

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to batch zoompan .mp4 using ffmpeg and cmd.

```
@rem windows 10 64-bit. How to zoompan .mp4 using cmd and ffmpeg.
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions 
MD "new folder"
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "zoompan=z='1+(1.4*in/300)':x='70*in/300':y='190*in/300':d=1" "new folder\%%~na.mp4"
```

[Docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html) at ffmpeg.org